# Releasing Hibernate Resources On Redeploy

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, out-of-memory

I have a web app running on Tomcat 6.0.35, which makes use of Spring 3.1.2, Hibernate 4.1.8 and MySQL Connector 5.1.21.

I have been trying to figure out what is causing Tomcat to keep running out of memory (Perm Gen) after a few redeploys.

Note: Don't tell me to increase Tomcat's JVM memory because that will simply postpone, the problem

Specifically, I made use of the VisualVM tool, and was able to eliminate some problems, including some mysql and google threads issues. I was also able to discover and fix a problem caused by using Velocity as a singleton in the web app, and also not closing at the correct time/place some thread local variables I was having. But I still am not  completely able to eliminate/figure out this Hibernate issue.

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Deploy my webapp from my development IDE
2. Open a tomcat manager window in my browser
3. Start VisualVM and get the HeapDump on the tomcat instance
4. Go the tomcat manager and redeploy my webapp
5. Take another HeapDump in VisualVM

My first observation is that the WebappClassLoader for the original webapp is not garbage collected.

When I scrutinize the retained objects from the second HeapDump, the class org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl features prominently which leads me to believe that it IS NOT being destroyed/closed by Spring or something along those lines (and hence the WebappClassLoader still having a reference to it).

Has anyone encountered this problem and identified the correct fix for it?

Comment: What's your IDE and OS Environment?

Answer (score 1):

I don't currently have an idea what could be amiss in your setup but what I know is that using [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu) you'll most likely find the actual leak(s).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards Plumbr. It's a great and easy to use tool, but it only gave me as much information as I was getting from VisualVM. But the tool that really got me to the root cause was Eclipse Memory Analyzer. And the kicker is, the problem was being caused by java.util.logging.Level. When I got this hint from Eclipse MAT, I dug around and found this blog: http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/07/03/enterprise-spring-best-practices-part-1-project-config/. From the information I gathered here, I switched my logging to use logback, and voila! The memory leak stopped. Great!

Comment: The information on this blog show how to use Eclipse MAT: http://blog.bosch-si.com/how-to-analyze-leaky-webapps/. And this site gives some good background regarding memory leaks: http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188158/How-to-Fix-Memory-Leaks-in-Java

Comment: Plumbr should tell you exactly which class is leaking, it usually does. You mean this bug http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6543126 ? Rather than using a logging framework (JUL, log4j, logback, etc.) directly, I'd program against [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) and _configure_ the actual logging backend thereby bridging slf4j-to-X.

Comment: You nailed it Marcel!!! That is precisely the problem. It was causing the tomcat's classloader to hang onto the entire object graph when I redeploy. It took my over a week to get to the bottom of it. And yes, I now programmed against slf4j-api and logback doing the actual logging. Thanks for showing me that bug report